# Segmentation Fault in c Hashing implementation

Tags: c, insert, gdb, hashtable, singly-linked-list

Trying to implement a Hash table in C. But I'm running into a segmentation fault in mu insertion process.

Node Struct Definition

```
//define a Nodes
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* nextPtr;
} node;
typedef node* nodePtr;
```

HashTable "methods"

```
//Insert values into the hash table
void insertVal(nodePtr* aNode, int val){
    nodePtr temp = (nodePtr) malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data = val;
    temp->nextPtr = NULL;
    //Insert the value at the hashtable
    if(!(*aNode)){
        (*aNode) = temp;
    }
    else{
        //Check if the first element is greater than temp's value
        //Append to the front of the value
        if(val < (*aNode)->data){       
            temp->nextPtr = (*aNode);   //set temp's next to point to head node
            *aNode = temp;              //reset the position of the head node
        }
        else if(val >= (*aNode)->data) {
            //Set up the walking nodes
            nodePtr prev = NULL;
            nodePtr curr = *aNode;
            //Walk through list until either is false:
            //  - val <= curr 
            //  - curr  == NULL
            while((val >= curr->data) && (curr)){
              //Check if the values are equal
              if(val == curr->data){
                //Insert them
                temp->nextPtr = curr->nextPtr;
                curr->nextPtr = temp;
                return;
              }
              prev = curr;
              curr = curr->nextPtr;
            }
            //at either condition,
            prev->nextPtr = temp;       //Insert inbetween the prev and curr
            temp->nextPtr = curr;
        }
    }
}

//Delete a value from the node Array
int delete(nodePtr* aNode) {
    nodePtr temp = *aNode;      //Get the leading node value
    (*aNode) = (*aNode)->nextPtr;//Move head pointer to next node
    int ret = temp->data;        //Get the value of deleted node
    free(temp);                 //Free Space allocated to deleted node
    return ret;                 //Return the deleted value
}

//Function to search a Node for a value
int* search(nodePtr* aNode, int val){
    int* valPos = calloc(2, sizeof(int));   //(0,1) = (arrayInd, nodeInd)
    memset(valPos, -1, 2);      //fill the memory with -1 and return
    if(!(*aNode)){
        return valPos;
    }
    int nodePos = 0;
    nodePtr curr = *aNode;
    //Walk node until:
    //  - value found
    //  - node's NULL
    while((val == curr->data) && (curr)){
        nodePos++;              //Increment the node position
        curr = curr->nextPtr;   //Walking the node
    }
    valPos[0] = val%10;         //get the val's array position
    valPos[1] = nodePos;        //Get the val's node level
    return valPos;    
}
```

main.c: Hash table is an array of nodes pointers. H(x) = x % 10, and H(x) is used for indexing values

```
int main(){
    int A[5] = {21,23,11,23,41};
    //Create a chaining hash table
    nodePtr* aTable = calloc(10, sizeof(nodePtr));      //Array of nodePtrs
    //Insert the values into the aTable
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        //Declare hash function
        int hasFunc = A[i]%10; 
        insertVal(&aTable[hasFunc], A[i]);
    }
    //Search for inserted values
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        int hasFunc = A[i]%10; 
        int *res = search(&aTable[A[i]%10], A[i]);
        if(res[0] != -1){
            printf("Value: %d found at array index: %d, and node level: %d\n", A[i], res[0], res[1]);
        }
        else{
            printf("value not found\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Error in GDB based debugger. And, as you can see it happens during the insertion of the final element of the array.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555555554b4 in insertVal (aNode=0x5555555592a8, val=41) at Chaining.c:27
27                  while((val >= curr->data) && (curr)){
(gdb) Quit

(gdb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition `(val >= curr->data) && (curr)` is bad because it will dereference `curr` *before* checking if `curr` is `NULL`.

The condition should be `(curr) && (val >= curr->data)` or (without extra parenthesis) `curr && val >= curr->data`.

Also note that casting results of `malloc()` family is [considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: It's also considered bad practice to [typedef pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers)